# Jupyter install issues on Windows

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this working. I've seen similar questions with answers that I have tried but do not resolve my issue.

I'm trying to follow the instructions to connect to a local runtime for Google Colab found here: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

I keep getting stuck at the point where I try to enable the jupyter_http_over_ws extension. The error message I get is:

```
$jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
Enabling: jupyter_http_over_ws
- Writing config: C:\Users\redacted\.jupyter
    - Validating...
      jupyter_http_over_ws 0.0.7 ok
Exception ignored in: <function Application.__del__ at 0x000002E8E45FA7A0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 955, in __del__
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 945, in close_handlers
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 683, in __get__
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 657, in get
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1428, in _notify_observers
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 273, in _observe_logging_default
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 278, in _configure_logging
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\logging\config.py", line 810, in dictConfig
  File "C:\Python\python3104\lib\logging\config.py", line 547, in configure
ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'console'
```

I am running on Windows 10 21H1. Python is 3.10.4 installed via the official 64-bit installer, and added to PATH environment variable. Jupyter is installed via pip as per the standard documentation.

I have also tried installing miniconda3 and installing jupyter and the extension via conda. The install appears to work just like with pip, but as soon as I try to enable it, same error about not being able to configure formatter.

Most of the other answers I have found said to make sure you install jupyter and the extension via the same method - meaning if you installed jupyter via conda, also install the extension using conda. I have tried that in both the python environment using pip as well as the conda environment via that package manager and I still get the same error. At this point I'm not sure what to do. I'm sure there is either a configuration error on my end or an incompatibility (not sure what version of Python people successfully used to run this).

Ultimately, I'm just trying to run S2ML Image Generator I found in a Colab notebook but I ran out of resources on the free tier so I figured I'd use local runtime to play around.

Comment: "Python is 3.10.4 installed via the official 64-bit installer, and added to PATH environment variable. Jupyter is installed via pip as per the standard documentation." <- You are doing everything right. If you can't figure this one out, one option is to use vanilla jupyter and throw the colab part out. You will have copy paste the code from colab to jupyter, but that's probably easier then trying to figure out what's wrong with that extension.

Comment: @psarka I may try that. I didn't realize that was possible, but it makes sense. And no, still haven't figured it out yet. Could it be related to the fact that Jupyter installs prefs to %USERPROFILE%\.jupyter and Python can't get to it? I confirmed the notebook pref files are also in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question as I was having the exact same error, also running Windows, also running Colab and trying to get local runtime working.

However, it now appears to be working.

Have you tried skipping step 2? Namely, rather than trying further to enable jupyter_http_over_ws, simply start the server as follows:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

and then try the connect to local runtime button.

Does that work for you? I had the same error, but that fixed it - my guess is it was already installed and enabled, and that was resulting in that error.